# How can I use the content of a vector as title in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use the **typed** content of a vector as title for a graph. Therefore (i think) i first need to convert the typed content to characters. And here it gets tricky....

I already tried to convert the content to "as.character()", "format()" etc...but in all cases i get the output of the dataframe itself en not just the content of the typen vector.

For example, say have I have 2 vectors...test_a and test_b

```
test_a <- read.csv2("test.csv", sep = ";", dec = ",")
test_b <- read_excel("test.xlsx")

x <- test_a ##(or test_b)
y <- as.character(x) ##this doesn't work :(


fig <- ggplot(x, aes(x = OUTCOME)) 
fig + geom_histogram(aes(color = SEX), 
                        breaks=seq(0, 1500, by = 1),
                        alpha = 1) +
        ggtitle(as.character(y))
```

As title of the graph I expect to get "test_a" or "test_b" as in "y" and not the numbers in test_a or test_b...Your help is appreciated a lot..

Comment: `y<-as.character` not `as.chracter`

Comment: What you're doing is assigning test_a to a new object x. This doesnot bring the name to  ggtitle but brings some values from test_a.

Comment: I just need the text after "<-"  as title....so no data from the dataframe. :)

Comment: @NelsonGon: thnx for the typo comment :p....The reason I assign test_a to x is that i have test_a to test_m...and after that there is a large chunck of code where x is returning.

Comment: Please share the output of `str(test_a)`.

Comment: @markus i just want to use the text "test_a" and not the values from test_a...

Comment: @NelsonGon: output of str(x)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 27916 obs. of  44 variables; str(test_a) is the Same ;)

Comment: From your comment above I thought test_a was a data.frame of data.frames.

Comment: I think you can use `lapply` with  a function that plots all the plots. Otherwise do it manually for each plot.

Comment: @NelsonGon true...I guess the simple question is: How could I convert all text after "<-" to a string that we might use as a header, title, etc :)

Comment: No need to save it as a variable. Just write it in `ggtitle("test_a")`. Otherwise x now takes on all data in test_a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `substitute` and `eval` here

```
x <- substitute(iris)

ggplot(eval(x), aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = x)
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is the same as just saying `title="iris"`. OP seems to want to "automate" it.

Comment: @NelsonGon Thanks for your comment. Updated the answer.

Comment: In this example, you still have to type "iris" everywhere. I acctually want this: 

x <- iris

ggplot(x, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
        geom_point() +
        labs(title = quote(x))

And the title should be "iris"

Comment: @Andrei Updated the answer, now it should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: @markus...you rock!! this works